# Custom UITableView Cell's Stack View Cannot Detect Super View Dimension

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nib, custom-cell

**Context** I have a UITableViewController with custom cells designed in a .xib file. In that .xib file I'm trying to set dynamic widths so splits the cell width into three subviews.

**Problem** is that the cell doesn't seem to be able to get the proper width, causing the cell to not fill the entire width. Here's a picture to better illustrate what I'm saying.

[cell_not_filling_width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQHwk.png)

**My Understanding** (Could be totally misunderstanding this) Setting the frame constraint in the .xib file is no good b/c the program won't know the width until runtime. In other words,  `awakeFromNib` (1.) loads before the screen width is determined... So idk how to fix this problem.. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

1. Presumably this is where the width is set - the width on my interface builder when I'm looking at the .xib file is the same when I print it out at `cellForRowAt`

**Notes** In my viewDidLoad function I've registered the nibfile as such so I don't think that's the problem. `tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "NewTableViewCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "newTableViewCell")`.

Here is some code that could be relevant.

NewTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class NewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var typeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var completedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var correctLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

The parentView is a view that contains the three subviews.

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxNhc.png)a picture of the .xib file

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLFXc.png) a picture of my constraints on the .xib file (it seems cluttered)

**UPDATE**
Tried the stack view approach: XCode just defines the width as the subview with the biggest width (according to how large the text is)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vlb0.png) is a picture of the current situation and the current constraints

I figured the [constraints on the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nFKI.png) may also be relevant:

**UPDATE2**
Ok I think I've found the problem; Basically the stack view cannot seem to detect the super view's length and width and it's dimension.

**NOTE** I have edited the constraints.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3VJu.png) is what it looks like if I set the width and height to a constant value. The stack view will actually go to the set constraints

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmX9M.png) is what it looks like if I take those constraints out. So it seems like the width and height are 0. Which is why I believe the constraints are not being adopted from the super view.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try to put every group of related elements in a stackView then everything in one stackView then set trailing leading top and bottom for that stackVew to Zeros

Comment: I tried this approach: Now getting three missing constraint errors. One for each of the subviews in the stack. All three missing constraint errors are saying that I need constraints for: X position or width.

I don't think the content view is giving the right constraints

Comment: To further clarify, that is if I unset the constraints 0 0 0 0 for the labels in each of the subviews. So if I don't unset the constraints for the subviews, XCode just defines the width as the subview with the biggest width (according to how large the text is).

Comment: Do you have a repository with your code so I can take a look?

Comment: No, unfortunately this isn't on a public repo :(. Is there a specific part of the code that I can share?

Comment: Which `distribution` option are you using for the stack view?

Comment: I have `fill equally` as the `distribution` option

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in cellforRow.

Add IBOutliet for stackviewWidth and set is dynamically  as shown below. Also check if the cell goes to the full width of the device by adding background color to cell.

```
if  let appDelegate =  UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
    let window = appDelegate.window {
    cell.stackViewWidthConstraint = window.bounds.width
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to add an IBOutlet for the stackViewWidth. I know how to add an IBOutlet for the stackView, but not for the width itself. Did you mean to add it for the stackView? If so, how do you refer to the width of the stackView?

I tried this `cell.stackView.frame.size.width = window.bounds.width`, but it didn't seem to do anything. Could you please lmk what I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Also set the background color to blue, but it doesn't seem to show.

Comment: Set  a width Constraint to the stackview and then drag width to the viewContoller file to set the Outlet - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G7sxHbOXzdYB3RxOmCSMquQjI67PxdnF

Comment: I can't seem to get around the error: `Cannot assign value of type 'CGFloat' to type 'NSLayoutConstraint?'`. How did you get around it?

Comment: Set a width say 100 to stackview and then add outlet to width constraint